(Soft-question) Need a guidance and some truth
I have MS in mathematics. I am 26 years old. I aspire to be a mathematician. Haven't landed phd anywhere. Infact I didn't apply for phd for the following two reasons:
1.) I am not sure I can get recommendation letter because I didn't put my best when I was in college and have mediocre grades mostly B's and C's and D's. Even got B in the MS thesis.
2.) Since, I didn't utilize my time well in college, I felt I am not that strong in any maths area.
It is irrelevant that I was a good student during my school days, but got distracted in my early 20s. But for the last year I have self studied rudin from the start, and I feel I am able to understand things, and my level has increased since last year. I can concretely see my progress. But the problem is I am doing right things at very late in my career. And I am still behind, there is a lot to cover, particularly lots of problems to solve, and I am past 25.  I was thinking to go for a Masters in CS and then do reading under some maths professor and then apply for phd from there with good recommendation. But I feel I will atleast be 29 till I enter a phd program. Any suggestion for me? Will that be too old to do a significant research in mathematics?
Right now as par as self study is concerned I am planning to complete baby rudin, linear algebra from Apostol calculus 2, Algebra (Group theory, rings and modules and Galois theory) at the level of Artin and other basic courses with problems. I have read theory of all these at some point, but hadn't solved problems previously so I am not fluent in these.
Could an experienced person guide me here. Please don't close this question. I know several others whom your esteemed answers might help and who are feeling miserable and lost.

What are you aiming for?? A math professor?? If no, then why are you even going for PhDs....I think getting a job in a MNC is the best idea (sorry if it's little bit rude...I'm still 18)

No, I am not going for job, I aspire to be a mathematician only.

Ohh then that makes sense....wait for some expert PPL to answer...I don't think I can be of any help here

Claiming self-study may be ignored.  Perhaps graduate schools in the US still take into account the GRE subject exam in math?  If so, that will demonstrate how successful your self-study has been.

The catch is that noone here can give a reasonable advice because noone here knows your background good enough. I am astonished that some people think they can do that but this is only what is good or was good for THEM , everyone is different. So speak with people in your neighborhood knowing you good enough to be able to give an adive that REALLY helps you.
